# TSD plugin wordpress and expo notifications

Tags: wordpress, react-native, push-notification, expo

i want to implement notifications on my expo app which is a wordpress client without ejecting the project does anyone have any idea on how to do this

i found this wordpress plugin TSD Push Notification but there is no documentation i don't know how to use it

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to learn Php and Wordpress. Don't ask me about those cause I'm not using Php/Wordpress. I see few documentation on the wiki of the GitHub project [Home](https://github.com/TheStanfordDaily/tsd-push-notification/wiki) and [REST-API](https://github.com/TheStanfordDaily/tsd-push-notification/wiki/REST-API) that might provide some clue.